# ServletResponse.flushBuffer -- does it block until my response is delivered?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Tomcat. The documentation for `ServletResponse.flushBuffer` says, *"Forces any content in the buffer to be written to the client. A call to this method automatically commits the response, meaning the status code and headers will be written."* 
But I cannot figure out from this: will my `doPost` method be blocked on this function until the client successfully receives the response? In case of poor connection times, may `ServletResponse.flushBuffer` freeze the thread? Or is the delivery performed asynchronously?

My goal is to measure the time it takes for my client to see the response. I want to measure times just before and just after the call to `flushBuffer`, but I am not sure if this time covers all the process of delivering the message to the client's socket.

Regards,
&rzej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will my servlet be blocked on this function until the client successfully receive the response?

No. The *current thread* will be blocked until the entire response has been written to the socket send buffer.

> In case of poor connection times, may ServletResponse.flushBuffer freeze the servlet?

No, only the current thread.

> Or is the delivery performed asynchronously?

Yes, but the response has to be buffered first, see above. If the buffer fills because the peer isn't reading or data hasn't been delivered and ACK'd, the writing thread will block until there is enough room.

Comment: it looks I was not very precise with my question. Let's add to the assumptions that my `doPost` / `doGet` methods do not launch additional threads and by blocking I mean blocking only the execution of `doPost` / `doGet` methods. My ultimate goal is to measure the delivery time of the response from within `doPost` / `doGet`

Comment: You can't, because of TCP buffering. All you can measure is the time it takes to get the response into the TCP send buffer. If you're not using chunked or streaming transfer mode, not even that: just the time to write into the Servlet container's internal buffer, probably a ByteArrayOutputStream. Your clarifications don't add anything. What blocks is the current thread, not the servlet or any of its methods, unless you have synchronisation.